# confd newbie trying to get if in template to work getting "invalid type for comparison"

Tags: docker, coreos, confd

I have exported a variable:

```
export myparam=one
```

I have template: file.tmpl :

```
myproptmpl =
{{ if eq .myparam "one"   }}
    {{ "one" }}
{{ else }}
    {{ "something else" }}
{{ end }}
```

And when I run `confd` I get:

```
# /usr/bin/confd -onetime -backend env
2016-04-20T15:21:58Z 8faae31d53a1 /usr/bin/confd[91]: ERROR template: file.tmpl:70:6: executing "file.tmpl" at <eq .myparam "one">: error calling eq: invalid type for comparison
```

I'm a newbie on `confd`. How can I compare an OS environment variable to values and based on them generate different resulting output file out of template?

Answer (score 1):

You need get the variable first and after that then you can compare.

Ex.:

```
myproptmpl =
{{ if eq (getv .myparam) "one" }}
    {{ "one" }}
{{ else }}
    {{ "something else" }}
{{ end }}
```